# Does anyone have better information about eBay's Large Merchant Services schema?

Tags: xsd, ebay-api, ebay-lms

I've been wrestling with eBay's Large Merchant Services API for a while. It's been rough. I finally have messages going all the way through their system, but I'm having issues with their schema. Apparently there are alot more restrictions than what is defined in the schema.

As an example, the schema defines shipping service options, which may look something like this:

```
  <ShippingServiceOptions>
    <ShippingService>USPSPriority</ShippingService>
    <ShippingServiceCost currencyID="USD">7.99</ShippingServiceCost>
    <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="USD">0.0</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
    <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
  </ShippingServiceOptions>
```

and is defined in their schema like so:

```
  <complexType name="ShippingServiceOptionsType">
    <complexContent>
      <restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
        <sequence>
          <element name="ShippingInsuranceCost" type="{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}AmountType" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingService" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}token" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingServiceCost" type="{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}AmountType" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingServiceAdditionalCost" type="{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}AmountType" minOccur ="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingServicePriority" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ExpeditedService" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingTimeMin" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingTimeMax" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}int" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="ShippingSurcharge" type="{urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents}AmountType" minOccurs="0"/>
          <element name="FreeShipping" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
        </sequence>
      </restriction>
    </complexContent>
  </complexType>
```

Where can I find valid values for `ShippingService`? I found an example where they has `USPSPriority`. That one works, but everything else I've guessed at (UPS, UPSGround, UPS2ndDayAir, etc) results in the entire thing getting returned with an error of `Invalid data`.

If anyone knows a list of valid values, or any other resources that better explains eBay's schema for Large Merchamt Services (LMS) please let me know.

As a side question, what exatly is a type of "{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}token"? JAXB currently converts it to a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things that might bring some clarity:

1. The eBay SDK only supports the Trading API, not Large Merchant Services.
2. eBay Large Merchant Service's XSD is located at `http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/merchantdataservice.xsd`. Note: This is not the same as the Trading API XSD.
3. The easiest way to have solved your ShippingService dilemma would have been going to AddFixedPriceItem's Call Reference and seeing `http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/AddFixedPriceItem.html#Request.Item.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions.ShippingService`

See where it says

> Applicable values: See
>   ShippingServiceCodeType

ShippingServiceCodeType links to the page you ultimately found.

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Very informative answer! BTW: you can make links like so (or use the "world-and-arrow" link icon): [eBay Large Merchant Service's XSD](http://developer.ebay.com/webservices/latest/merchantdataservice.xsd)

Comment: Hi @Overflow Helper, I want to work for listing items in once on e-Bay. Kindly help me out how can I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Answer to side question:

xs:token is described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_string.asp).

as

> The token data type also contains
>   characters, but the XML processor will
>   remove line feeds, carriage returns,
>   tabs, leading and trailing spaces, and
>   multiple spaces.

For your main question, you'd have to be asking eBay.

Comment: Yeah I have this question in on their development forums as well, just thought I'd see if anyone here knew the answer. I've found their dev forums to be spotty at best as far as a resource for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the [answer concerning Shipping Service](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/ShippingServiceCodeType.html). Their (eBay's) documentation is much better than I had initially realized, although it still can take a bit of poking around to find the data - it does appear to be there.

[EBAY Trading API Call Reference](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/index.html)